# Prove that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(O)$ is open for each open set $O$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

1. How would you proceed in the below, or have I led myself to a dead-end?

   - Let $O$ be an open set from $\mathbb{R}$. $O \subset \mathbb{R}$
   - Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, be the domain of $f$. i.e. $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For notation ease.
   - Then $f^{-1}(O) = \left\{ d \in D | f(d) \in O \right\}$
   - $f^{-1}(O)$ is open. [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843909/prove-that-the-inverse-image-of-an-open-set-is-open).
   - The above implies: $\forall x \in f^{-1}(O)$, there is a $r > 0$ s.t. $\left\{ y \in \mathbb{R} | |y-x| < r \right\} \subset f^{-1}(O)$

Now the above looks very similar to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the continuity, but the statement is about the domain of function $f$. So I am stuck.

2. How come there is a [counter-example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468774/f-is-continuous-iff-f-1u-is-open-for-all-open-u) to this proof (I must be understanding it incorrectly)?

I know there is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975566/prove-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbr-is-continuous-iff-f-1o-is-open-for) question. But I am asking about my steps in 1.

Comment: If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a function, then its domain is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I wanted to write $d \in D$ in the definition of $f^{-1}(O)$ for better clarity.

Comment: There is no counter-example, there are examples of continuous functions that are not open.

Comment: @PeterMelech got it, thanks

Comment: You seem to be confusing open functions with continuous functions. $f$ is continuous iff the preimage of open sets is open, and $f$ is open iff the image of open sets is open. The counterexample shows that $f$ continuous doesn't imply $f$ open.